# OSError: [Errno 95] Operation not supported: '/content/drive/Mask_RCNN' on Google Colab

Tags: google-colaboratory

Hello trying to use saved weights for a Mask RCNN model within colab and keep incurring the error message below. I have tried different ways of accessing the .h5 problem, which was an issue before, and now I have hit a brick wall. I have tried to train different parts of the model, nothing works. Nothing specific is available on google colab with these circumstances.
The following is the cell that throws the issue:

````
    # Training dataset.
    dataset_train = linkedinDataset()
    dataset_train.load_dataset(dataset_dir, "train")
    dataset_train.prepare()

    # Validation dataset
    dataset_val = linkedinDataset()
    dataset_val.load_dataset(dataset_dir, "val")
    dataset_val.prepare()

    # *** This training schedule is an example. Update to your needs ***
# 
#  
#  
    print("Training network heads")
    model.train(dataset_train,
                dataset_val,
                learning_rate=config.LEARNING_RATE,
                epochs=5,
                layers='heads')```



```Training network heads
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-19-174a93609e58> in <module>()
       17             learning_rate=config.LEARNING_RATE,
     18             epochs=5,
---> 19             layers='heads')

  2 frames
   /content/Mask_RCNN/mrcnn/model.py in train(self, train_dataset, val_dataset, learning_rate, epochs, 
   layers, augmentation, custom_callbacks, no_augmentation_sources)
   2334         # Create log_dir if it does not exist
   2335         if not os.path.exists(self.log_dir):
  -> 2336             os.makedirs(self.log_dir)
   2337 
   2338         # Callbacks

    /usr/lib/python3.6/os.py in makedirs(name, mode, exist_ok)
    208     if head and tail and not path.exists(head):
    209         try:
    --> 210             makedirs(head, mode, exist_ok)
    211         except FileExistsError:
    212             # Defeats race condition when another thread created the path

    /usr/lib/python3.6/os.py in makedirs(name, mode, exist_ok)
    218             return
    219     try:
   --> 220         mkdir(name, mode)
    221     except OSError:
    222         # Cannot rely on checking for EEXIST, since the operating system

    OSError: [Errno 95] Operation not supported: '/content/drive/Mask_RCNN'```
````

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot use

```
'/content/drive/Mask_RCNN'
```

You should save to either

```
'/content/Mask_RCNN'
```

Or, if to use Google Drive,

```
'/content/drive/MyDrive/Mask_RCNN'
```

Comment: Okay, It really works, but why couldn't I use any other folder, for instance, /content/drive/some_name folder?

What's wrong with this /content/drive/*?

Comment: /content/drive is where you mount to Google Drive. Google drive will show either `My Drive` or `Shared Drive` there. You cannot create any other directories there. It's not a real place to create a directory.